# How to use re.sub in Python

Tags: python-3.x

Please help me replace a particular string with re.sub()

```
'<a href="/abc-10063/" target="_blank">'
```

needs to be

```
'<a href="./abc-10063.html" target="_blank">'
```

Wrote a script below

```
import re
test = '<a href="/abcd-10063/" target="_blank">'
print(re.sub(r'/abcd-[0-9]','./abcd-[0-9].html', test))
```

which returns

```
<a href="./abcd-[0-9].html0063/" target="_blank">
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all your regular expression is incorrect. It will match `/abcd-1` only.
You need to change your regex to `/abcd-[0-9]+`. Adding a `+` will match all the numbers. Also to match the trailing `/`, you need to add that in your regex.
So final regex will be `/abcd-[0-9]+/`.

Now to reuse the matched content in substitution you need to create groups in your regex. Since we want to reuse just the `/abcd-[0-9]+`and not the `/`. Put `/abcd-[0-9]+` in group, like this: `(/abcd-[0-9]+)/`.

Now we can use `\1` to use matched group in the substitution, where 1 is the group number. If you wanted to use second group, you will use `\2`.

So your final code will be:

```py
import re
test = '<a href="/abcd-10063/" target="_blank">'
print(re.sub(r'(/abcd-[0-9]+)/', r'.\1.html', test))
```